# OCaml Type and Type Inference

Tags: types, ocaml

I am having a bit of trouble determining OCaml Types. Why is the type for the following expression for:

```
let f x y z = z (y::x)

'a list->'a->('a list->'b)->'b
```

And what does the `z (y::x)` mean? I know `y::x` means to append an element `y` to list `x`, but what does the `z` do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

First, note that `y::x` *prepends*, not *appends*, an element `y` to list `x`.

The four parts of the type of `f` can be explained as follows:

- The first argument to function `f` is `x`, so the first part of the type of `f` is `'a list`, which is consistent with the use of `x` as a list in the definition of `f`.
- The second part of the type of `f` is `'a`, which is consistent with prepending element `y` to the list `x`, since if `x` is an `'a list`, `y` must be an `'a`.
- The third argument of `f` is `z`, which must be a function taking an `'a list` as its first argument given how it's used in the definition of `f`. Therefore the third part of the type of `f` is `('a list -> 'b)`, where `'b` is the return type of `z`.
- Finally, the return type of `f` is the same as the return type of `z`, so the final part of the type of `f` is `'b'`.